# Why we use yield to get Sessionlocal in Fastapi with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        return db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I got this code snipped to get Sessionlocal in fastapi with Sqlalchemy. Well, when I used return instead of Yield. My code still works. Then, I do not understand the reason of using Yield. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> #### Well, when I used return instead of Yield. My code still works. Then, I do not understand the reason of using Yield.

It's a great question, the answer is, **yes there's a reason** to use yield instead of return.

SQLAlchemy has a [**Connection Pooling**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html) mechanism by default. That means with yield you are creating a single session for each request. When you use `return` you are using a single database connection for all your app.

Isn't it clear? Let's visualize it to make things more interesting.

[image]

So what do we have in this example?

- A connection pool that holds 5 different connections.
- 2 endpoint
- 3 incoming requests.

When you use yield it would look something like this underneath because it goes to an endpoint, asks something to the database and yield creates a new Session object every time. It provides a transactional scope around a series of operations, but using `return` there instead of `yield` will just return that session object.

Answer (score 14):

There is a fundamental difference, when you use a `return`, the closing is performed **before** the function returns the `db` object, in fact you are returning a *closed* `db` object. [Because](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

> When `return` passes control out of a `try` statement with a `finally` clause, that `finally` clause is executed **before** really leaving the function.

Otherwise, when the `yield` is used, the `finally` code block is executed **after** the request has been processed and the response **has been sent**. You can read more about [dependencies with yield here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/).

Why your code continues to work, I cannot tell without seeing the whole code.

Comment: Exactly, this should be answer. It is documented in FastAPI: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/